# Could individual developer publish office web add-in

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, appsource

Is it possible for individual developer account to publish office web add-in to AppSource, like outlook web add-in? By [this article](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-store-docs/blob/master/docs/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center.md) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center), it says that individual developer account can publish office web add-in to Office App Store. However, when I try to add Office Store program in [partner center](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard), it always asks for registration as a company. The screenshot is shown in the below link. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Yes, definitely. There are a variety of add-ins that have been published to App Source from individuals.  We recently migrated to Partner Center and your question about company name is a good one. Let me check with the team on that.

Comment: Have you signed up for a AAD developer account? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/open-a-developer-account

Comment: When I login in Partner Center, it shows that I am individual developer already, but I am not sure if I am AAD developer account. Should I register for AAD developer to enable publishing office add-in?  How could I achieve that? It seems that the link tells how to register developer account which I am already. Thanks.

Comment: If you're new to Partner Center and don't have a Microsoft Network Account, create an account using the Partner Center enrollment page.

If you're already enrolled in the Microsoft Partner Network, create an account directly from Partner Center using existing Microsoft Partner Center enrollments.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/open-a-developer-account#create-an-account-using-the-partner-center-enrollment-page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/manage-account-settings-and-profile

You can check out the above URLs for more info.

Comment: under the Roles and Permissions section of your profile, kindly check if you see Active-Directory set to yes. if its yes, then it means you are on AAD.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I wanted to enroll to office program as an individual, and i got the same issue. I got this response to my support ticket "We got a response from Engineering team stating that its by design and you will not be allowed to use your personal account. You will have to use your work account to access or enroll for Office program."

Comment: Why is Microsoft responding in the comment section rather than the answer section?

Comment: @KeyurPatel-MSFT any updates? I’m an individual developer trying to publish to Appsource but Partner Centre still requires a business verification as of today.